# React How to simplify this code

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React, and I would like to know if there is a way to simplify this code:

Original:

```
renderSubmitBtn() {
    if (this.state.displaySubmit) {
        if (this.state.submitActive) {
            return <button className="active" ref="submit" type="submit"></button>
        } else {
            return <button ref="submit" type="submit"></button>
        }
    } else {
        return <button ref="submit" type="submit" style={{display: 'none'}}></button>
    }
}
```

This code returns a submit button (with different styles) depending on the current state.

What I want to achieve:

```
renderSubmitBtn() {
    const btn = <button ref="submit" type="submit">
    if (this.state.displaySubmit) {
        if (this.state.submitActive) {
            return btn.addClass('active')
        } else {
            return btn
        }
    } else {
        return btn.addStyle({'display': none})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
 renderSubmitBtn() {
     let classname = "", style = {}; 
      if (this.state.displaySubmit){ 
          if(this.state.submitActive) {
             classname = "active";
         }
      } else {
           style = {"display":"none"}
    }
       return <button className={classname} ref="submit" style={style} type="submit">
    }
```

Or

```
 renderSubmitBtn() {
       return <button className={this.state.displaySubmit && this.state.submitActive : "active":""} ref="submit" style={!this.state.displaySubmit ? {"display":"none"} : {}} type="submit">
    }
```